# jQuery .load() method not working w/ CMS articles

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-management-system, cross-domain

I am building a little widget that displays information from a different section of the site (Joomla) when users mouse over a particular menu option.  Based on the behavior I am seeing, it seems to me like this method doesn't work w/ something like a CMS article because I keep getting an empty (see: http://cl.ly/1k3n151n3o0d1f2A1e3k) response.

The code below works great and does exactly what I want it to do when I reference a static file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Div/Scraping Testing</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://scripts.dri.edu/Other/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("#wifi").mouseover(function()
    {
      $("#show").load('wifi.php #wifi');
      $("#show").show();
    });
    $("#wifi").mouseout(function()
    {
      $("#show").hide();
    })
  });

  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>

    </header>

    <div id="main" role="main">
      <div id="nav">
        <center>
          <a href="wireless.php" id="wifi">WiFi</a> || <a href="#">Test</a>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div id="show" style="display:none;">
        <center><h3>Wireless Info.</h3></center>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you would expect the data inside the div w/ ID="wifi" is displayed in my "show" div.  When I change the JavaScript to the following:

```
  $("#show").load('http://cmsurl.com/is/is-network-access/22-wireless-access/ #wifi');
```

I get the empty response from the picture I link to above.  Is this just a limitation of the .load() method in the sense that it can't parse the data from a CMS article and needs a static file or am I just going about things in the wrong way?

Comment: Is the page you are running on on the cmsurl.com domain? If not this will not work as XHR cannot be executed cross domain.  You'd need to use JSONP.  For a simple explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript.

Comment: SoWeLie: It was in fact on a different domain which was causing the issue.  Once I moved the script to the same domain everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into restrictions imposed by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). In short, AJAX calls to a different domain are prohibited and will always fail.

You need to either use JSONP (mostly applicable to data returned by APIs) or [proxy the request through your own server/domain](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html).

Comment: BOOM!  You are exactly right, I moved the file from my testing area to production (where it is on the same domain as the URL I am passing to the .load() method) and I am good to go.  Thanks for the info!